# Can we write simple css syntax is .scss file?

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

**Can we write simple css syntax is .scss file?**

**When we use .scss should we wrie anything directly in .css file?**

This is the example code of.scss file

```
$blue: #3bbfce;
$margin: 16px;

.content-navigation {
  border-color: $blue;
  color:
    darken($blue, 9%);
}

.border {
  padding: $margin / 2;
  margin: $margin / 2;
  border-color: $blue;
}
```

Sometime I just want to write a simple style like

```
h1 {font-size:3em}
```

**then where we should keep it. in .css only in .scss only?**

**Should we never touch .css file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you go sass, don't use css at all, no point.

you CAN have sass generating css files, and css files you manually edit and seperately include in your HTML.   But if you are writing it, then may as well stick with sass for everything.  Very soon you will find yourself writing things with variables and in a lot more "modular" way and depending on the extended syntax of sass.

Comment: +1 So even if we want to write default css styling we should write in .scss? right?

Comment: right.  unless there is some  weird reason that I cant imagine for why you want to directly write css  ( maybe because you need a particular structure for some other program to interpret the css for some weird reason ).     But if there's no 'reason'  then just become sass coders :)

Comment: OK so we can and we should keep normal css declarations in .scss file.

Comment: @KeithNicholas, to show example of "weird reason", look at this: `#test p:media(min-available-width:350px and max-available-width:750px) {background:#8a2be2;}` for `@element queries`. For now, it's impossible to put this syntax into SASS, because preprocessor is trying to..do something with this, instead of just leave it as it is.

Comment: @JitendraVyas asking for CSS in SCSS and answer is for SASS.

Comment: @sajalrajabhoj  sass has two different syntaxes...   https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax

Comment: I had the same question, and the reason is that I am just now learning sass and want to use it in a Reactjs project that is halfway built. So I installed CRA + sass and it seems like I just need to change the extensions of App.css and Index.css into scss. I already have some css in there, however it looks like there is not problem with that.

Comment: just as a followup for anyone interested, I no longer use scss/sass  I just use tailwind with standard css when needed